# Kafka-connect logs in docker container

Tags: java, docker, log4j, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have a kafka connect jar which needs to be run as a docker container. I need to capture all my connect logs on a log file in the container (preferably at a directory/file - /etc/kafka/kafka-connect-logs) which can later be pushed to localhost (on which docker engine is running) using volumes in docker. When I change my `connect-log4j.properties` to append into a log file, I see that no log file is created. If I try the same without docker and run the kafka connect on a local linux VM by changing `connect-log4j.properties` to write logs to a log file, it works perfectly but not from docker. Any suggestions will be very helpful.

`Docker File`

```
FROM confluent/platform

COPY Test.jar /usr/local/bin/
COPY kafka-connect-docker.sh /usr/local/bin/
COPY connect-distributed.properties /usr/local/bin/
COPY connect-log4j.properties /etc/kafka/connect-log4j.properties

RUN ["apt-get", "update"]
RUN ["apt-get", "install", "-yq", "curl"]
RUN ["chown", "-R", "confluent:confluent", "/usr/local/bin/kafka-connect-docker.sh", "/usr/local/bin/connect-distributed.properties",  "/usr/local/bin/Test.jar"]
RUN ["chmod", "+x", "/usr/local/bin/kafka-connect-docker.sh", "/usr/local/bin/connect-distributed.properties", "/usr/local/bin/Test.jar"]
RUN ["chown", "-R", "confluent:confluent", "/etc/kafka/connect-log4j.properties"]
RUN ["chmod", "777", "/usr/local/bin/kafka-connect-docker.sh", "/etc/kafka/connect-log4j.properties"]

EXPOSE 8083

CMD [ "/usr/local/bin/kafka-connect-docker.sh" ]
```

`connect-log4j.properties`

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger = INFO, FILE

# Direct log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.FILE.File=/etc/kafka/log.out
# Define the layout for file appender
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.conversionPattern=%m%

log4j.logger.org.apache.zookeeper=ERROR
log4j.logger.org.I0Itec.zkclient=ERROR
```

`kafka-connect-docker.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
export CLASSPATH=/usr/local/bin/Test.jar
exec /usr/bin/connect-distributed /usr/local/bin/connect-distributed.properties
```

It works fine when I am using the default `connect-log4j.properties` (appends logs to console), but am unable to create a log file in docker. Also, same process without docker works fine (creates log file ) in local VM.

Comment: Have you tried to declare the volume right away and put the file directly on the volume folder?  Something like VOLUME /etc/kafka in your docker file and then on docker run mapping this volume?

Comment: Thank you !! This helped :-)

Comment: I placed the outcome as answer as well, see below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Result of the discussion:

Declare the volume right away in the dockerfile and configure your logging configuration to place the log output directly to the volume. On docker run (or however you start your container) mount the volume and you should be fine.

Comment: How do i make kafka connect to log to a file rather stdout by changing docker compose environment variable, coz i dont have control over creating or modifying existing kafka-connect image.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Stdout is the standard way for everyone to read the logs and if you change it you will break a lot of monitoring tools that rely on that. If you still want to do so you could have a look here https://www.scalyr.com/blog/how-to-redirect-docker-logs-to-a-single-file